# passing an array to a function but logs as undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-handling

I have 2 event listeners and they both push the element that is clicked into 2 separate arrays. These console.log in the event listener functions as expected, however when I pass them into a `move` function they both return undefined.

I've tried it with just passing the element that is selected into the function as well with the same result.

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click' , function(params) {
        el.classList.add('selected')
        selectedPieces.push(el)
        console.log(selectedPieces)
        moveBy(selectedPieces)
    })
})

document.querySelectorAll('.square').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        el.classList.add('target')
        targetPieces.push(el)
        console.log(targetPieces)
        moveBy(targetPieces)
    })
})

function moveBy(selected,target) {
    console.log(selected)
    console.log(target)
}
```

Comment: inside of your `click` event listener, is the `el` variable defined?

Comment: How exactly is this expected to work?  The modification of the `selectedPieces` and `targetPieces` are done in the click event handlers of (at least) two different elements.  And you are only passing one variable into `moveBy` for either one.

Comment: @taplar I think that answers my question then, I want to have a selectedPiece and a targetPiece get passed into the moveBy function, where I can handle the movement of the pieces. I thought I could pass in 2 params from different eventListeners and it would handle it

Comment: No, that's not how function arguments work.  For each invocation, if you don't pass them, they don't get passed.  There is no "I remember you previously passed this argument" logic.

Comment: @taplar hmm that kind of kills the code I have here then. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 0):

So I did create a work around in this. It involved sending the addEventListeners to their own functions, then adding them to an array, then sending that array to it's own function which then allowed me to move things around.

Only thing wrong with this version is that it only works one time, so I'm currently working through what is causing it to only fire once.

```
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click' , addselected)
})

document.querySelectorAll('.square').forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', addtarget)
})


function addselected(selected){
    console.log('---addselected---')
    var select = selected.path[0]
    moveList.push(select)
}

function addtarget(target){
    console.log('---addtarget---')
    if (target.path.length === 7){
        var tar = target.path[1]
    }else{
        var tar = target.path[0]
    }

    moveList.push(tar)
    moveBy(...moveList)
}


function moveBy(...moveList) {
    console.log('---moveBy---')
    let moveTarg = moveList[2]
    let moveSel = moveList[0]
    if (typeof moveTarg === 'undefined') {
        console.log('not working')
    }else{
        moveTarg.appendChild(moveSel)
        moveList = []
    }
    console.log(moveList)
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

well

```
function moveBy(selected,target) {
    console.log(selected)
    console.log(target)
}
```

has two paramaters.

```
        moveBy(targetPieces)
```

but you pass only one parameter in.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: But if I'm passing in both from different event listeners, does that have a bearing on how the function handles it?

Comment: You are never passing in both.  You are only passing in one.

Comment: you are not passing it individually one at a time into the same function,  you are creating a copy of the function with each invocation, and in each invocation of the function, you pass one variable... the second variable is never defined.